# java methods multiplying elements with in an array using a loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, int

Deﬁne a Java method named weightedSum() that takes two integer arrays as its arguments. The 
method uses a loop to multiply corresponding elements of the two arrays together (i.e., it multiplies the ﬁrst argument of each array together, followed by multiplying the second element of each array together, and so on) and returns the sum of those products (which is also an integer). You may assume that both arrays are of equal length.

```
public int weightedSum(int [] a ,int [] b)


    {
        int value;
        int sum ;

        for (int i = 0 ; i < a.length ; i++)
        {
            value = a[i] * b [i];
            value  = value +value ;

        }

        return value;
```

I am having trouble writing this method out for my assignment . I under stand it accepts to arrays but i am having trouble writing out the loop itself so that it multiplies each individual element of the array with its counterpart in the opposite array so pos [1] * pos [1] and then add the two values togather with pos [2] + pos[2] and  to get the sum total for all the values

Comment: Hint: you've got a variable called `sum`, but you're not using it...

Comment: to test your method, use a similar printing messages as described here - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html  - to understand what happens in each iteration. Start with 2 arrays with 3 elements defined in each and add some printing in your code to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

below are the changes needed in your code. Basically you never updated the variable sum after you compute the product of corresponding elements in the two arrays. Also you might wanna use long type to store the result of the sum & the product as the int value might overflow if the elements in the array are sufficiently large.

```
public long weightedSum(int [] a ,int [] b)
{
    long value = 0;
    long sum = 0 ;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < a.length ; i++)
    {
        value = a[i] * b [i];
        sum = sum +value ;

    }

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: This still won't compile. `sum` isn't definitely assigned. (I'd also change the scope of `value`, but that's a slightly different matter.)

Comment: initialize the sum with zero
like int sum = 0

Comment: "returns the sum of those products (which is also an integer)" This no longer complies with the spec.

Comment: @Cruncher I changed the contract on purpose to indicate to the OP that if int is returned there is a possibility of incorrect result due to overflow. The OP is free to decide if he/she wants to keep the return type as int/long

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public long dotProduct(int [] a, int [] b) {
    if (a == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("a array cannot be null");
    if (b == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("b array cannot be null");
    if (a.length != b.length) throw new IllegalArgumentException("arrays must have equal lengths");
    long sum = 0L;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        sum += a[i]*b[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the code looks correct, however the second line in the loop should not be changing the value variable, the sum variable should be updated with the value.
something like sum += value.
then return sum.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
public class Demo
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    
        System.out.println("Enter n :");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
    
        Integer[] arr = new Integer[n];
        System.out.println("Enter Elements :");
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            arr[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }
    
        //Ascending Array
        Arrays.sort(arr); 
        System.out.println("Elements Are :");
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    
        //Descending Array
        Arrays.sort(arr,Collections.reverseOrder()); 
        System.out.println("Elements Are :");
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    
        //Product Of First Four Elements Of Array
        int product=1;
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            product=product*arr[i];
        }
        System.out.println("Product : "+product);
    }
}

/* Output

Hello World
Enter n :
5
Enter Elements :
4
5
9
8
6
Elements Are :
4
5
6
8
9
Elements Are :
9
8
6
5
4
Product : 2160

*/

import java.util.*;
public class DemoNew
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.out.println("Enter N : ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
    
        Float[] r = new Float[n];
        System.out.println("Enter Distances : ");
    
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            r[i]=sc.nextFloat();
        }
    
        System.out.println("Distances : ");
       for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(r[i]);
    }
    
    for(int i=0;i<r.length;i++)
    {
        if(r[i] == 0.0)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid");
            break;
        }
        else if(r[i] < 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid");
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            //Descending Array
            Arrays.sort(r,Collections.reverseOrder());
            System.out.println("Distances in Descending Order Are :");
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
            {
                System.out.println(r[j]);   
            }
            

            System.out.println("3 Max Distances Are :");
            for(int k=0;k<3;k++)
            {
                System.out.println(r[k]);                   
            }
            
            List<Float> list = Arrays.asList(r);
            System.out.println(list);
            
            
            

            /* Float[] ar = new Float[r.length];
            for(int m=0;m<r.length;m++)
            {
                ar[m]=r[m];
            }
            
            System.out.println("Final Ans :"); */
            
            break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What is your query? please ask your question in more detail.

Answer (score -2):

Change to this:

```
value += a[i] * b [i];
// value = value + value;
```

Also initialize `value` to `0` before using it.
Also remove the `sum` variable.

Comment: That won't compile, and it certainly won't return the sum.

Comment: Suggesting to comment out some code is pointless, if it is not needed then it should be deleted

Comment: @JonSkeet sum is never used, in the original code, it is always updates value

Comment: Downvoters are too quick here :) My answer is just fine.

Comment: @peter.petrov: Your initial answer was *not* just fine. It's not the downvoters who were too quick: it was your answer, which was incorrect. I've removed the downvote now, but you can't really complain about getting downvotes for an incorrect answer. (It still isn't a *good* answer IMO, in that it doesn't really explain anything...)

Comment: I don't complain, I find it funny ;)

Comment: @haifzhan: My comment didn't mention the `sum` variable; it was referring to the sum of the values, which is what the question was asking. Peter's initial answer didn't return the sum, so was incorrect.

Comment: Yes, Jon, the very initial one was incorrect. I don't argue about that. Still, downvoters are too quick... click click click ;)

Comment: @peter.petrov: Look at your comment, which criticised the behaviour of those downvoting your answer, which was *definitely* initially incorrect. Does that look like you finding it funny, or does it look like a complaint?

Comment: @peter.petrov: If an answer is incorrect, it's unhelpful, thus deserves a downvote. Are you suggesting that before downvoting, one should hang around for a while just in case the answer is fixed? Bad idea IMO - I'd say it's up to the *answerer* to make sure the answer is correct before posting. In this case, *you* were too quick, not the downvoters. (And no, that's not saying my answers are always correct to start with either - but if someone downvotes an incorrect answer of mine, I would *never* say they're "too quick". They're behaving entirely appropriately.)